# Time complexity of Monotonic stack question

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

As I understand , the time complexity of this code is O(N)
The for loop will iterate just once , so the time complexity accounts for O(N)
but there is a while loop inside the for loop

So there is a while loop nested inside the for loop
Why are we ignoring the time complexity of that?

```js
var dailyTemperatures = function(temperatures) {
    let result = new Array(temperatures.length).fill(0);
    let stack = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++) {
        while(stack.length > 0 && temperatures[i] > temperatures[stack[stack.length - 1]]) {
            let index = stack.pop();
            console.log('hello');
            result[index] = i - index;
        }
        stack.push(i);
    }
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because while loop is simply poping stack elements one by one and there can not be more than N elements pushed inside the stack ( every element pushed once ). So even though while loop is nested inside for loop it will not execute more that N times.

Comment: So, the inner loop will not be counted as nested loop until its covering `N` elements, won't it?

Comment: It is a nested loop but main thing to notice here is that both loop do not run from 1.. to N ( if that would have been the case complexity would have been O(N2) ).

Answer (score 0):

It becomes confusing if you look at it like nested loops.
The approach in monotonic stack is that every element is pushed once into the stack and popped once too. So for every element there will be max 2 operations.
Thus it becomes 2 * O(n) , which translates loosely to O(n).